# JSON Error: Request Entity Too Large: head

Tags: json

I'm encountering a problem with JSON request size.
I've converted a picture into Base64, but the string is too long, as you can think.

```
{
    "login":"test",
    "password":"test",
    "avatar":"YGFTTftgtgtg/HUUgyGFTF [...] "
}
```

How can I bypass this problem

Anyone with an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: JSON doesn't care how long anything is. _What_ is giving you the error?

Comment: My error : Error: Request Entity Too Large: head. 

It's du to the value of "avatar"

Comment: @Ranpie49 where you see this error?

Comment: You already told us the error. What software is giving it to you and when? Describe your process and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry.
I use Talend Open Studio. A component that receives my REST Request transfroms values of all parameters in order to save them in LDAP.
I don't know if i answer to your question ?

I test the request with RESTConsole (Chrome app), I've encoutered this error in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try from a different browser. Most likely chrome is the problem. There are couple similar cases reported that I could see. Probably try firefox's rest client addon/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cookies in the browser. Sometimes cookies will be corrupted.